# Documentum DFS, renaming dm_user (user_name attribute)

Tags: c#, web-services, documentum, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs

After changing some user's **user_name** attribute with DFS Object web service consistency checker fails. It seems Documentum uses user_name as foreign key in other documents and renaming this attribute on dm_user doesn't change all foreign keys of this user.

Anyone knows how to correctly change user_name value and all its 'dependencies'? Is this even possible with DFS?

Oh, I am using .NET c#, so any solution have to be compatible with that.

Consistency checker report:

> WARNING CC-0002: User '*FirstName
>   LastName*' is referenced in dm_group
>   with id '1200400186008806' but does
>   not have a valid dm_user object 
>   ....

It goes like this for about 50 users.
after that comes:

> WARNING CC-0007: ACL object with
>   r_object_id '4500000160051328' has a
>   non-existent user '*FirstName LastName*'
>   ...

and about 50000 more lines for ACL, sysobjects,...

tnx

**EDIT:** some clarifications

**EDIT 2:** added consistency checker report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured it out:

What you have to do is create new dm_job_request with following attributes:

```
            object_name = "UserRename",
            job_name = "dm_UserRename",
            method_name = "dm_UserRename",
            request_completed = false,
            priority = 0,
            arguments_keys = "OldUserName,NewUserName,report_only,unlock_locked_obj".Split(','), //stringarrayproperty
            arguments_values = "test,test123,F,T".Split(',') ////stringarrayproperty
```

After that you manually run dm_userrename job. I tried to set priority to 1 (that was supposed to be "run Now" option) but it didn't automatically start dm_userrename

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Dm_userrename job is the way to do it. Having the user_name as the foreign key was not a great design choice but we have to live with it.

Comment: Thanky you. So how do I use it? First rename user (like I already have with DFS) and than run this job? Can I run jobs with DFS?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean buy renaming dm_user, but I expect that you're going to get a heap of problems, considering it's pretty fundamental to the whole platform.

Documentum is effectively an object-orientated database, so you should be able to create a sub-type of dm_user, call it what you like and it should behave in the same way.

Comment: I mean changing value of attribute user_name of certain dm_user. I want to change data of a few instances of dm_user, not scheme

Comment: OK, I see.  If you change the user_name attribute then you will orphan the records that used it. You'll have to devise a mechanism to perform the change. I don't think there's a built in way.

Comment: So by hand for all orphaned objects? No other way? Someone mentioned DFC *might* have it, but didn't know anything else.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a DQL query to do the update, which you could issue through DFC.
Something like

```
UPDATE dm_document set user_name='new name' where user_name='old name'
```